# Testing a rest service with JUnit

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey

I wrote another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469143/implement-a-junit-test-for-a-rest-service/41469644#41469644) previously. There I got an error executing a JUnit test on a rest service because the JSON was just a String for Jersey.

```
public class MachineResponseTest {

    private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/dni-fe/home"

    @Test
    public void testDevice() {

        WebResource resource = Client.create().resource(BASE_URI);
        resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("{\"name\":\"123456\",\n");
        sb.append(" \"country\":\"Spain\",\n");
        sb.append(" \"company\":\"xxx\",\n");
        sb.append(" \"model\":\"1.10.0\"\n}");      

        MachineResponse result = resource.post(MachineResponse.class,sb.toString());
    }
```

Then I tried to convert the StringBuilder into a `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject` object and to return a String insted of a POJO; in this way the previous error disappeared:

```
try{

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("{\"name\":\"123456\",\n");
  sb.append(" \"country\":\"Spain\",\n");
  sb.append(" \"company\":\"xxx\",\n");
  sb.append(" \"model\":\"1.10.0\"\n}");   
  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
}
catch(JSONException e){
....
}

String result = resource.post(String.class,jsonObj);
```

For example, suppose I have this POJO class:

```
public class ItemBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7438046484680798158L;
private String name;
private String country;
private String company;
private String model;

public ItemBean() {
    super();
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}
```

I tried to use this POJO to build my test, for example:

```
ItemBean item = new ItemBean();
item.setName("123456");
item.setCountry("Spain");
item.setCompany("xxxx");
item.setModel("1.10.0");

String result = resource.post(String.class,item);
```

but the test ended with an error:

> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException:
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body
>   writer for Java type, class it.dni.rest.models.DeviceBean, and MIME
>   media type, application/octet-stream, was not found   at
>   com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:151)

So, my target is to map an object in JSON and viceversa directly but Jersey is not doing it for me. What can I do to enable this mapping using Jersey in Junit test?

Comment: Your example does not make a lot of sense: the `resource` you reference in the last code example is only instanciated in the method `testDevice` of the test class, which actually does not assert or verify anything? Please revise your question to  a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok but if my test gets an error I can't try anything.

Answer (score 2):

There are few libraries that really help with unit testing REST webservices. Rest-assured: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured is one and Unirest http://unirest.io/ is another. I just started using Unirest and it is super easy to use for JSON. Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try Jersey Test for testing

> *Jersey Test Framework originated as an internal tool used for verifying the correct implementation of server-side components.
>   Testing RESTful applications became a more pressing issue with
>   "modern" approaches like test-driven development and users started to
>   look for a tool that could help with designing and running the tests
>   as fast as possible but with many options related to test execution
>   environment. Current implementation of Jersey Test Framework supports
>   the following set of features: pre-configured client to access
>   deployed application support for multiple containers - grizzly,
>   in-memory, jdk, simple, jetty able to run against any external
>   container automated configurable traffic logging Jersey Test Framework
>   is primarily based on JUnit but you can run tests using TestNG as
>   well. It works almost out-of-the box and it is easy to integrate it
>   within your Maven-based project. While it is usable on all
>   environments where you can run JUnit, we support primarily the
>   Maven-based setups.*

Refer https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html